# Fatal signal 11 when using SIFT detector from opencv4android

Tags: android, opencv, fatal-error, feature-detection, sift

I try to use the SIFT Feature detector from Opencv4Android

My code is the following

```
       public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
        switch (status) {
        case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:
            {

   fileimage = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/Pictures/263.jpg");

 image=Highgui.imread(fileimage.getAbsolutePath(),Highgui.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);

    FeatureDetector fd = null ;

    fd= FeatureDetector.create(FeatureDetector.SIFT);

    MatOfKeyPoint keypoints= new MatOfKeyPoint(); 

    fd.detect(image, keypoints);
```

My log file is the following

```
       -24 09:40:19.636: A/libc(12695): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x0  in tid 12695 (mples.tutorial2)
```

Comment: @Gabe Sechan it is not the same question

Comment: Yes, it is.  Go there and learn how to deal with a signal 11.  If after learning that you still need additional help come back here and ask a far more specific one.